JMeter Chrome Driver Config Issue
I have a JMeter test where I open a Chrome browser to simulate a visitor. I use the Chrome Driver Config activity to open the Chrome browser. However, since the ChromeDriver 127 update, a search engine popup appears. This causes the test to fail. Is there a way to block this popup or another solution? The popup needs to disappear.
Thanks!
I tried changing the additional arguments in the Chrome Driver Config, but it didn't solve the issue.

It can be worked around by adding --disable-search-engine-choice-screen argument to Chrome browser startup command line

More information: How to Use JMeter for Selenium WebDriver Testing
